# .htcaccess redirect no www to www with SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

For a long time we have had our site running without www in front, but we have recently been forced to make a change.

We recently changed from domainhere.com to www.domainhere.com. We already had a redirect from http to https, but need to change the redirect from https://domainhere.com to https://www.domainhere.com.

**We used this code. How do we make it still redirect to HTTPS but with www in front?**

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.skarpeknive.dk/$1 [R,L]
```

**We found this on Stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work. The site bugs on domainhere.com then**

```html
#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work.  Did you clear your browser cache before testing the rule?

Comment: Hello. I did. I would say it should work too. Maybe it just takes a while for my computer to adjust. Coud you test it? The site is skarpeknive.dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is proxy issue so,try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: Changes nothing. If you open skarpeknive.dk does it send you to https://www ? It must just be my cache bugging even though I cleared.